# Navigate to a specific path through Nodeport

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud-private

I have created and deployed an application on ICP 2.1. Have exposed NodePort as my service. Iam able to navigate to the url from the Nodeport. How do i go to a specific path on the url directly from the Nodeport. Iam using yaml file to create the deployment and service. Where should i specify the path??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i go to a specific path on the url directly from the Nodeport

The short version is that you don't, since a `NodePort` is merely an exposure of an existing `port:` from a `Service`.

The medium length version is that using an ingress controller (such as the "default" nginx one) would allow you to [add an app-root](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/README/#app-root) to the `Ingress` resource, and then use the `NodePort` belonging to the ingress controller rather than the `NodePort` of the upstream `Service` itself. I'm pretty sure [all of the ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-catalog/) support that kind of behavior since it's a fairly common scenario.

The long version is that you can manually put something like `nginx` or `haproxy` between your `Service` and the upstream `Pod` to artificially inject a URI prefix, with the disadvantage that if you wish to do that more than once, you'd be better off using an `Ingress` resource so that functionality is handled for you in a standardized way.